# Apache - Allow access to globally aliased directory without auth

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

I got a virtualhost, which has some access restrictions configured like this:

```
<Location "/">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/domain/htdocs/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

In addition to that, I have the following `conf`-file:

```
Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge/ "/var/www/letsencrypt/"

<Location /.well-known/acme-challenge/>
    # Security Options
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    ForceType text/plain
    RedirectMatch 404 "^(?!/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[\w-]{43}$)"

    # Do not redirect to https or perform other rewrites
    RewriteEngine off

</Location>
```

I need `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` to be accessible without auth.

I have already tried adding different variations of `Require all granted` to my `conf`-file, but to no avail.

How can I make `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` accessible without authentication for all virtualhosts? (I do not want to modify any virtualhosts, this virtualhost is just an example).

Answer (score 4):

There is no possibility to override the `<Location />` statement from your virtualhost-context in the server-context. From [apache doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging):

> Sections inside `<VirtualHost>` sections are applied after the
>   corresponding sections outside the virtual host definition. This
>   allows virtual hosts to override the main server configuration.

The order of merging is (last merged group wins):

1. `<Directory>` (except regular expressions) and .htaccess done simultaneously (with .htaccess, if allowed, overriding `<Directory>`)
2. `<DirectoryMatch>` (and `<Directory "~">`)
3. `<Files>` and `<FilesMatch>` done simultaneously
4. `<Location>` and `<LocationMatch>` done simultaneously
5. `<If>`

Apart from `<Directory>`, each group is processed in the order that they appear in the configuration files.

`<VirtualHost>` is not allowed inside `<If>` so `<Location>` is the last merged.

## But

If you only serve the site in a https vhost (what would be reasonable, because of the authentication), you can do the following (without affecting your https vhost):

## Apache v2.2

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Include letsencrypt-well-known.conf
  RedirectMatch permanent ^(?!/\.well-known/acme-challenge/)(.*) "https://example.com$1"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  <Location "/">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/domain/htdocs/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
  </Location>
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

`letsencrypt-well-known.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
  ProxyPass /.well-known !
</IfModule>

Alias /.well-known/ /var/www/html/.well-known/

<Location /.well-known/acme-challenge>
  Options None
  Require all granted
</Location>
```

## Apache v2.4

```
<Macro RedirectTo $protocol $domain>
  <If "'${well_known_enabled}' == 'On' && %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/\.well-known(/|$)#">
    # Do nothing
  </If>
  <ElseIf "tolower(req('Host')) != '$domain' || tolower(%{REQUEST_SCHEME}) != '$protocol'">
    Redirect permanent / $protocol://$domain/
  </ElseIf>
</Macro>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Include letsencrypt-well-known.conf
  RedirectTo https example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  <Location "/">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/domain/htdocs/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
  </Location>
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

`letsencrypt-well-known.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
  ProxyPass /.well-known !
</IfModule>

Define well_known_enabled On
Define well_known_root "/var/www/html"

Alias /.well-known/ "${well_known_root}/.well-known/

<Directory "${well_known_root}/.well-known">
  Options None
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Location /.well-known/acme-challenge>
  Options None
  Require all granted
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Apache 2.4, you can add an `Require expr` statement to the first location block and evaluate the request URI, like so:

```
Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/.well-known/acme-challenge/.*#
```

or something along that line (syntax not actually tested). The strange `m#` syntax is an alternative form for regexes to be able to use `/` in the string.

`expr` docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

Comment: I am explicitly looking not to change the virtualhost (as noted in my question) :/

Comment: @Zulakis: Then I believe you are out of luck. Citing the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging): `Sections inside <VirtualHost> sections are applied after the corresponding sections outside the virtual host definition. This allows virtual hosts to override the main server configuration.` This means your `<Location>` block will override anything you put on a global level

Comment: Even if the non-virtualhost <Location> selector is more specific, I guess? Well, my question is looking for a solution that solves exactly this issue ;)

Comment: Yes, `Apart from <Directory>, each group is processed in the order that they appear in the configuration files.` Is the VHost in question 443 or 80?