# Apache: How to "hide" a subdomain but serve over https

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, .htaccess, https

I will freely admit my ignorance - or perhaps enough knowledge to be dangerous.

I have a subdomain `http://db.<mydomain>.com` that serves the phpMyAdmin utility. It's currently in a directory with an Apache directive to require a valid-user from .htaccess which made sense at the time, because I don't want to expose the phpMyAdmin login page to the general public.

The problem this created was trying to use cert-bot to create SSL certs for my site, it can't validate the ACME challenge because the challenge can't get past the .htaccess restriction.

How can I simultaneously serve this subdomain over https while also requiring an additional layer of security before a user can see the phpMyAdmin login page?

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName db.<mydomain>.com
        ServerAlias www.db.<mydomain>.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomains/db/phpMyAdmin
    </VirtualHost>
    <Directory "/var/www/subdomains/db">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile "/var/www/.htpasswd-users"
        require valid-user
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <Directory "/var/www/subdomains/db">
>     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all
>     AuthType Basic
>     AuthUserFile "/var/www/.htpasswd-users"
>     require valid-user
> </Directory>
> ```

You should remove the `Order` and `Allow` directives. These are the old-style Apache 2.2 directives and are formerly deprecated on Apache 2.4 and are likely to cause conflicts (but they aren't required anyway).

Although curious why you have a `<Directory>` section for `/var/www/subdomains/db`, yet the `DocumentRoot` is defined as `/var/www/subdomains/db/phpMyAdmin`?

Then add an additional `<Directory>` section for the `/.well-known/` file-path in which you allow unrestricted access - so the certbot can "validate the ACME challenge". For example:

```
<Directory "/var/www/subdomains/db/phpMyAdmin/.well-known">
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's at least three ways to solve this:

1. Use the [DNS challenge](https://serverfault.com/questions/750902/how-to-use-lets-encrypt-dns-challenge-validation), requiring no HTTP connection
2. [Disable basic auth for `.well-known/`-path](https://serverfault.com/questions/821476/apache-allow-access-to-globally-aliased-directory-without-auth) which is used by certbot.
3. Use the standalone module of certbot. This will lead to 10-20 seconds of downtime

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to add access restrictions for the virtual host like this:

```
<Directory "/www/docs/db">
    <RequireAll>
        Require ip <localip> <certbot host-name>
    </RequireAll>
</Directory>
```

For more information about `Require` directive you can visit [Apache doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require).

Comment: LE doesn't publish the IP's they come from, and they publicly state the addresses are subject to change without notice. This is mentioned in [their FAQ](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/) under *What IP addresses does Let’s Encrypt use to validate my web server?*

Comment: @vidarlo, hostname is also acceptable in this case.

Comment: They don't use reverse DNS either. There's simply no reliable way to whitelist them based on address. In addition, there's no reason to do it this way.